# How to encrypt "InputData" to use my smart contract to make it unreadable

Tags: solidity, web3js, contract-development, contract-invocation, evm

Hello every body i get in trouble if someone can help me ...

I'm buying token with my smart contract, have a look :

[image]

Its is so clean to see my Tx and decode it .. because all adress are clear and this is the problem

I want make a clear Tx and encrypt it with that this can't be decoded like this one :

[image]

As you can see there is no way to know what is the token buy and the token use to buy that is a great encoded Tx that nobody can break..
So how can i proceed to do this please, need i encode my Tx or Self destruct it ?

This is my Solidity Smart Contract function to Buy :

```
 function Buy(address fromDECODED,address toDECODED,uint256 amountIn,address to) public {
uint256 amountOutMin = 0;

IERC20(fromDECODED).transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), amountIn);
IERC20(fromDECODED).approve(ROUTER, amountIn);

IUniswapV2Router(ROUTER).swapExactTokensForTokens(
  amountIn,
   amountOutMin,
    PathBuy(fromDECODED,toDECODED),
     to,
      deadline
      );
    }
```

And i call my function from my JS to execute a Buy order

Comment: The information should come from somewhere and the smart contract need to be able to decode it, which means everyone can decode it. if you are looking for privacy then look for aztec or polygon-nightfall

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i make seach aztec is a network and nightfall is the a way too but i want learn how to do it into my solidity with an example..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- To obfuscate the input so that etherscan cannot decode it : **YES**.
- To hide your contract's activity (ERC20 transfer): **NO**.

Although you can obfuscate and hide your input data, people can see your contract interacting with ERC20 address and use transfer & approve on that contract address. They can simply look at the `Internal transactions` or `Log` tab on etherscan to view it easily.

To obfuscate the input, it's actually quite simple, change your function name to some random string and change your function signature to use some encoded bytes. The simplest method for encode and decode is to use XOR operator. using the code below and do not submit ABI or source code to Etherscan, it would help you to avoid etherscan decoding your input.

```
    uint256 constant not_secret = 0x7050c9e0f4ca769c69bd3a8ef740bc37934f8e2c036e5a723fd8ee048ed3f8c3;
    function random_obfuscated_string_0x1234567890(uint256  a, uint256 b) public{
        address real_addr_a = address(uint160(a ^ not_secret));
        address real_addr_b = address(uint160(b ^ not_secret));
    }
```

To encode data you do the same thing , XORing with `not_secret`. As the name suggest, it's not a secret and its only purpose is to prevent etherscan. It also doesn't protect your contract from being revert engineered or disassembled by other users if they want to do it.

I would not recommend doing it though, because it doesn't help anything other than preventing the `Input Data` field from being decoded. People still can see "Token Transfered", "Internal Transactions", and "Logs". All these things clearly expose what your contract buy and sell.

Related question : [How to obfuscate solidity smart contract](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/138539/is-there-any-example-of-obfuscation-or-mechanism-for-ethereum-smart-contract)

---

Update: OP asks for the step-by-step guide. So here it is (you have to understand these concepts (XOR cipher - symmetric encryption and the above description about what your contract can hide) before using it, otherwise it's very dangerous to copy and use online answers for solidity without understanding it fully:

Step 1. Choose a cipher key, it's the `not_secret` constant here. You can change it to any random number.

Step 2. Use the key to encrypt your input: Example:

1. Token_1: `0x55d398326f99059ff775485246999027b3197955`
   Encrypt Token_1 using the key `not_secret`:
   Encrypted_token_1 = uint256(uint160(token2)) ^ not_secret = `50801780122331352337026042894364481186943364210072012998642427539196337619350`
2. Token 2: `0x2170Ed0880ac9A755fd29B2688956BD959F933F8`
   Encrypted_token_2 = uint256(uint160(token2)) ^ not_secret =
   `50801780122331352337026042894659144872731148500323806259612097858952170752827`

Step 3. Use Encrypted_token_1 and Encrypted_token_2 as input of the function:

```
random_obfuscated_string_0x1234567890(50801780122331352337026042894364481186943364210072012998642427539196337619350, 50801780122331352337026042894659144872731148500323806259612097858952170752827)
```

Step 4. The contract decrypts the input data using the same key to get the original addresses 0x55d39... and 0x2170Ed... .

To encrypt and decrypt, it's better to write your own code because online services may use different padding, hard to guess how they implement.
You can craft a local contract like this to test (e.g. on remix):

```
contract Test{
    uint256 constant not_secret = 0x7050c9e0f4ca769c69bd3a8ef740bc37934f8e2c036e5a723fd8ee048ed3f8c3;
    function decrypt(uint256  a, uint256 b) public view returns (address, address) {
        address real_addr_a = address(uint160(a ^ not_secret));
        address real_addr_b = address(uint160(b ^ not_secret));
        return (real_addr_a, real_addr_b);
    }
    function encrypt(address token1, address token2) public view returns (uint256, uint256){
        return (uint256(uint160(token1)) ^ not_secret, uint256(uint160(token2)) ^ not_secret);
    }
}
```

I used `encrypt` function in this contract to produce the outputs in step 2 above.

Extra: Using uint160 for the key `not_secret` is considered simpler for the code and you may be able to use some online service to check encrypt-decrypt, you may try.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE : ok it work** perfect and big thanks you but i make a **mistake** asking my question and i have the solution right now :

It work because we provide the address of **token1** and **token2** in the **SOLIDITY**

To change this tokens we need do like this :

Need to provide the **token1** & **token2** from the **JAVASCRIPT Script **

---

In JS **need  do this**  :

**1st Step ** call function **encrypt**(*of my contract*) to get the encrypted data >> **await** *answer*.

**2nd Step ** call function **Buy**(*of my contract*) to make the **swap** wished.

---

After many hour i don't find how to do this only in **SOLIDITY** i'm able to change token address only with the step above with JS :

So i need call 2 function actually in my JS to answer the question.

Maybe we can do it only in **Solidity** i don't find ?? after many test ... i mean :

- Send from **JS** the true address to **SOLIDITY CONTRACT** .
- **CONTRACT** encrypt it.
- **CONTRACT** call Buy **function** with the **decryption into** the **function** Buy

Thanks you so much !
Please provide me donation address !

Sincerely Mike

Comment: I updated the answer, just hope that you and maybe your team read what is possible, what is not, and what are the related concepts. All the best.

Comment: Please mark my answer as correct, thank you :)